# Xamarin Forms Start/Sleep/Resume not being called when using MVVMCross.Forms

Tags: mvvmcross, xamarin.forms

we have a project based on Xamarin.Forms, using MVVMCross-Forms.

I'm using code like this on MvxIosSetup:

```
    protected override IMvxIosViewPresenter CreatePresenter()
    {
        Forms.Init();

        var mvxFormsApp = new MvxFormsApp();

        mvxFormsApp.Start += (s, e) => { StartMessage.Publish(); };
        mvxFormsApp.Sleep += (s, e) => { SleepMessage.Publish(); };
        mvxFormsApp.Resume += (s, e) => { ResumeMessage.Publish(); };

        return new MvxFormsIosPagePresenter(Window, mvxFormsApp);
    }
```

But those event handles are never called, I've similar code for UWP that also does not work. Only one that is working fine is Droid.

I've searched everywhere for a working sample, but so far nothing related to this events.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue that is fixed in 2.1.0 where OnStart / OnResume is not called for UWP or WinRT or WP8.

If MVVMCross is hooking into these events then that is why its not working. Upgrade to the pre-release to test if it fixes your issue or if there is something else at play here.

Comment: Forgot to add, I'm already using pre-release, v2.1.0.6508-pre3.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is you are not attaching the events soon enough. Looking at the MvxFormsApp file (which I assume you are using the one included in the package, then it will relay the event). 

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Forms/blob/master/MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.Core/MvxFormsApp.cs

Comment: Agreed, but even than, I would lose the Start one, but should not lose the Sleep/Resume ones (that is what I'm actually interested).

Comment: If you actually copy the code and have it in your application, do the OnStart, OnResume's work? I can't see any issue with Mvx hence trying to see if its an issue with XF. I'm not too familiar with Mvx but where do you call LoadApplication? The MvxFormsIosPagePresenter doesn't do that. I assume its where CreatePresenter is called and it gets the Application back out of the new Presenter?

Comment: Copying the code would not work, as the dependency on MVX would not allow this.

LoadApplication varies by platform, but it is usually something like this on the 3 I'm using:

`var presenter = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewPresenter>() as MvxFormsWindowsUWPPagePresenter;`
`LoadApplication(presenter.MvxFormsApp);`